# Is "People exercising everyday are healthy" wrong?

Tags: adjectives, present-participles

Can a present participle be used like present progressive adjectives to talk about general nouns? Is this sentence right?

> People exercising everyday are healthy.

or do I need to use who+conjugated verb?

> People who exercise everyday are healthy.

Can present participle be used only to talk about specific things?

> The boy eating the spaghetti is my brother.

Comment: Are you asking if it's syntactically correct or if it's *right*?

Answer (score 1):

> People exercising everyday are healthy.

This implies that "people" are healthy while exercising everyday, but not necessarily when they stop exercising.

> People who exercise everyday are healthy.

This is more idiomatic.  But "everyday" is an adjective/adverb, whereas you really want a noun as the object of "exercise".  So it should be:

> People who exercise every day are healthy.

Almost.  Exercising every day does not, in the real world, guarantee health.  About all one can really say is:

> People who exercise every day are healthier [than those who don't].

(And that comes with a few caveats.)

Comment: Hi, HotLicks. Why would you *really* want a noun as the object of to *exercise* when it could be used intransitively. If you replace *every day* with adverbs like *regularly*, *daily* or *on a daily basis*, it still makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I think "People who exercise every day are healthy." is the correct wording.

Also, note that it's "every day", not "everyday."